# SceneKit SCNNode init(mdlObject:) missing?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I'm using Xcode 7.3.1, Swift 2.x, iOS target is 9.3. I can find convenience init `init(MDLObject mdlObject: MDLObject)` in [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNNode_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SCNNode/nodeWithMDLObject:), but I don't see it in my project. I opened standard game project starter, SceneKit is imported. I've tried:

- Double checking iOS version
- Adding `import ModelIO`
- Finding "mdlObject:" in header files in SceneKit.framework - not found
- Looking for alternative methods (maybe Apple moved it somewhere) but there are no other inits with that parameter, no class function, nor I found any corresponding export function in `MDLObject`
- Cleaning project...

I can see all SceneKit classes, and I can create MDLAsset (part of ModelIO, can return MDLObjects) instance.
Any ideas, maybe I've overlooked something obvious?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

the following should do

```
import SceneKit.ModelIO
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why I couldn't find it in headers. And it's kind of weird to have SceneKit.ModelIO beside ModelIO and SceneKit...

Comment: It is very dumb that this has to be done separately.  Not mentioned in the docs.