# Argument labels '(MDLObject:)' do not match any available overloads in Xcode 10

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I'm trying to use a .obj file as SCNNode, I tried this:

```
let url = URL(string: "stone.obj")
let asset = MDLAsset(url: url!)
let object = asset.object(at: 0)
let node = SCNNode(MDLObject: object)
```

but I have an error (Argument labels '(MDLObject:)' do not match any available overloads). 
Is anything changed in the last version of swift?

Comment: That does not compile in Xcode 9 either. But have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/39426285/1187415.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have `import SceneKit.ModelIO`

Replace this

```
let node = SCNNode(MDLObject: object)
```

with

```
let node = SCNNode(mdlObject: object)
```

see here in [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1419841-init)

Comment: You have to **import SceneKit.ModelIO**